# simplifying a sum with modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p\!\geq\!3$ be a prime and $n\!\in\!\mathbb{N}$. For $i\!=\!1,\ldots,n$ let $w_i\!=\!2i\!-\!n\!-\!1$. Let $n\%p$ denote the remainder in the integer division of $n$ by $p$. Can the following sum be expressed only with $n$ and $p$?
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\min\big(w_i\%p,\:p\!-\!(w_i\%p)\big)$$

Sorry for the odd question, but this expression popped up in my research, and I'm struggling to present it more aesthetically in an article.

If not, is there at least a lower bound which is sharper than $\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\rfloor\frac{p^2-1}{8}$?

Comment: The summand is also $p \| w_i/p \|$ where $\|r\|$ is the distance between the real number $r$ and the nearest integer.  This may make the problem more appealing or intuitive even if it doesn't help solve it.

Comment: Is $w_i\%p < 0$ when $w_i < 0$?

Comment: @DavidK: No, $0\leq w_i\%p<p$. So $\min\big(w_i\%p,\:p\!-\!(w_i\%p)\big)$ is the minimal number of $1$'s that have to be added or subtracted to make $w_i=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: I haven't had sufficient free time yet to work up a full answer, but I have noticed that the first $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ terms are a mirror image of the last $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ terms; if you remove the $\frac12$ factor and discard all terms where $w_i$ is negative, you get the same result. Also, the difference between the sum and your lower bound is just a sum of (zero or more) consecutive even numbers and (zero or more) consecutive odd numbers, depending on whether $n$ is even or odd and on the sign of $n \bmod p - n/2$.